# How to rewrite this bash command on windows batch?

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

I have this shell (bash) command on linux. I want to make this happen in Windows `.bat` (CMD).

Linux command:

```sh
export STATUS="$(cat STATUS_FILE)-${STATUS_CODE:-0}"
```

`STATUS_FILE` contains status of the current server. You can say -for example- "running".
`STATUS_CODE` is the status code of the server. If it given, it is bigger than `1`. If this `env` not available then `0` as default.

So the output and `STATUS` will be: `running-0` or `running-2`

I know environments can be translated as `%STATUS_CODE%` but how do I read from status file without newline (one line text stripped if any) and assign it to new variable called `$STATUS` together with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me for now:

```
set /p FSTATUS=<STATUS_FILE
SET STATUS=%FSTATUS%-%STATUS_CODE%
```